# strange syntax error in node-apn library

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification

I am trying to implement push notification server with nodejs. 
I downloaded node-apn library and tried to initiate sample code.
When I run sample code file, I got an error "unexpected syntax token ,".
So I looked code line where syntax error occurs.

```
const Endpoint = require("./lib/protocol/endpoint")({
    tls,
    protocol,
});
```

This seems strange syntax but everybody else use node-apn library fine
except me. I get syntax error if includes only one line of code below.

require("apn");

is there anyone who experienced this?
or is there anybody who successfully implemented this node-apn library?
any assistance will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's ES6 code for an [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and it's shorthand for:

```
const Endpoint = require("./lib/protocol/endpoint")({
  tls: tls,
  protocol: protocol,
});
```

If you're using an older version of Node, which comes with an older version of V8, you may have syntax errors.

Comment: I am getting this error all over the module.. I fixed one file with the above code and it worked well. But now I am getting error in other files. How do i got about it. Plz help

Comment: @MendonAshwini The best fix is to update your Node.js installation. Anything prior to v6 is going to be increasing amounts of trouble going forward.

Comment: But I cant update my node.js .. as other moudles which i might have used be dependent on the older version of node.js. I m using v0.12.7.

Comment: Usually Node's pretty good when it comes to upgrade compatibility, so I'd at least try with a newer version of Node. v0.12 is defunct completely, you won't see any support for that going forward.